# Data of child component is passed on to it next sibling component on update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components (RequestList and Request). Parent component lists the array of objects fetched from the server into its child component as props by calling the `getRequestList()` method.

From the child component an object can be deleted by calling the parent component's method `deleteRequest(request_id)` which was sent as props.
In the parent component method, it deletes the object by sending a delete request to the server. If it was succeful, then it calls the same method to fetch the lists of requests `getRequestList()`.

The problem I am facing is that, in the child component, there is another method to vote the request `VoteRequest()`. If the voting was successful, it will update the vote status of a Request component, or if it fails, it will show an error.

Now suppose there is already an error, in one of the Request component (child) eg, first request object. And I delete that request, and the request list is updated. Then for some reason I don't know why, the error from the deleted component is still present on its next Request component. What am I doing wrong here?

Parent component (RequestList.vue):

```
template
        <ul id="request_list" v-if="request_list_data.length > 0">
            <li v-for="request in request_list_data">
                <request :request_id="request.id"
                         :deleteRequest="deleteRequest"
                         :updateVotes="updateRequestVotes">
                </request>
            </li>
            <p class="error" style="margin-top: 20px;" v-show="request_error !== ''">{{request_error}}</p>
        </ul>

script
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                request_list_data: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getRequestList() {
                const url = this.$store.state.website + '/api/activities/-requests/?ordering=-id';
                this.$http.get(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.request_list_data = Object.assign([], response.data);
                    })
            },
            deleteRequest(request_id){
                const url = this.$store.state.website + '/api/activities/-requests/' + request_id + '/';
                this.$http.delete(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.getRequestList();
                    })
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getRequestList();
        }
    }
```

Child component (Request.vue):

```
template
        <div class="request">
            <div class="vote-action" @click="VoteRequest('down')">&#x25BC;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="_data">
                <div class="request_error" v-show="vote_error !== ''">
                    <p class="error">{{vote_error}}</p>
                </div>
                <button v-show="selfrequest" class="deleterequest_btn" @click="deleterequest()">Delete your request</button>
            </div>
        </div>

script
    export default {
        name: 'request_wrapper',
        props: {
            request_id: {
                type: Number,
            },
            updateVotes: {
                type: Function
            },
            deleteRequest: {
                type: Function
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                vote_error: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            VoteRequest(vote_type) {
                this.vote_error = '';
                if (this.$store.state.user_logged_in) {
                    if (vote_type === 'up') {
                        const data = {
                            'request': this.request_id,
                            'vote_type': true
                        };
                        this.PostVote(data);
                    }
                    else if (vote_type === 'down') {
                        const data = {
                            'request': this.request_id,
                            'vote_type': false
                        };
                        this.PostVote(data);
                    }
            },
            PostVote(data) {
                const url = this.$store.state.website + '/api/activities/-request-votes/none/voterequest/';
                this.$http.post(url, data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.updateVotes(this.request_id, response.data.votes);
                    })
            },
            deleterequest() {
                this.deleteRequest(this.request_id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's `request_error` defined? I don't see how it connects to `request` items in loop. Besides, (maybe irrelevant, but) you should always give unique `key` for each item in a `v-for` loop (otherwise it can lead to weird views behavior).

Comment: @wostex `request_error` is defined in the parent RequestList component. It will show if there was any error while fetching the request items from the server. I will try using `key`. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @wostex Yes, your were right. `key` was the problem here. Thank you. Could you can answer it so that I can accept it and may be help others as well.

Comment: There's no such property in `data` or computed property in you code. Is it omitted from the published code? One more thing I'd like to suggest: when you delete an element - you can splice it from your state storage, and then send a delete request to your server in a background. In this case you don't need to fetch the same data every time you delete one element on your frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always a good practice to add unique `key` to elements inside `v-for` loop.

Using unique `key`s allows to avoid weird behavior when you delete items from an array rendered with `v-for`. It helps Vue decide weither to render new data or show the cached one: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Starting from Vue 2.2 using `key` is required when looping components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for